# How to update view when scope does not change

Tags: angularjs

there is a textarea to input. And two buttons to click.

```
      `<textarea ng-bind="msg"></textarea> 
       <div class="cancel-btn" ng-click="is_hide=false;"></div>
       <div class="submit-btn" ng-click="submit_card()"></div>`
```

### What is the process ?

input some characters in textarea, then click 'submit-btn', scope will save the 'msg'.  But if click 'cancel-btn', scope won't save the msg.

### What do I want ?

After I save msg, then input and click 'cancel-btn', I want to the textarea's innerHTML is scope.msg instead of input.

### #

Now, I want to exec `$scope.$apply()` to update dom, but alert error `$digest already in progress`.

### #

Maybe I need `ng-model` the textarea, and use the other param `saved_msg`save the `msg`, when click 'cancel-btn', make the `msg = saved_msg`. But, there are some convenient ways ?

-------------------update   6/25-----------------

```
`<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <div ng-class="{'selted':cid == 0}" data-cat="0"></div>
 <div ng-class="{'selted':cid == 1}" data-cat="1"></div>
 <div ng-class="{'selted':cid == 2}" data-cat="2"></div>
 <textarea ng-bind="msg"></textarea> 
 <div class="cancel-btn" ng-click="is_hide=false;"></div>
 <div class="submit-btn" ng-click="submit_card()"></div>
 </div>
```

`In fact, I use some directive by`jQuery` to change the dom class, when click 'cancel-btn', I want to refresh the dom decide to scope. 
It may be similar to $render.

--------------------update 6/26--------------
Thank for your help. I find a way to solve the problem.I add a `div#main` to contain what I want to save/refresh. ps: care for some change!
The follow is my way. Maybe you have better way, welcome to share!

```
`<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <div id="main">
 <div ng-class="{'selted':cid == 0}" data-cat="0" selt></div>
 <div ng-class="{'selted':cid == 1}" data-cat="1" selt></div>
 <div ng-class="{'selted':cid == 2}" data-cat="2" selt></div>
 <textarea ng-bind="msg" id="msg"></textarea>
 </div> 
 <div class="cancel-btn" ng-click="reset()"></div>
 <div class="submit-btn" ng-click="submit_card()"></div>
 </div>`
```

In controller,

```
`app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile)           {
    $scope.reset = function(){ //reset depend on scope
        $('#main div').removeClass('selted');  
    //the dom maybe change, need clear 'selted' class first
     //compile(dom)(scope) 
        $('#main').html($compile($('#main').html())($scope));
    }
    $scope.save = function(){  //save the scope
        $scope.msg = $('#msg').val();
        $scope.cid = $('.selted').index()+1;  
    }
}]);

app.directive('selt', function(){  
  //this is directive, only change class on dom
    return function(scope,ele){
        ele.click(function(){
            ele.addClass('selted').siblings().removeClass('selted');
        })
    }
});
```

`

Comment: ng-bind basicly binds the value of msg once, instead of continously 'updating' it like ng-model. So indeed, I think you should use ng-model.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `$setPristine()` on your form.  see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#!/

Comment: The second approach is the normal way of doing it. ng-model is always equal to what you see in the textarea, you can copy it to other variable when you click some button.

Answer (score 0):

1 - You need to replace `ng-bind` of your `textarea` with `ng-model`, to update the scope while you are typing on it.

2 - To provide a `cancel` like that, in a simple manner, replace the `ng-click` content with a function, like `cancel(formName)`. In your controller:

```
angular.module('exampleApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.is_hide = false;
        $scope.msg = null;

        $scope.cancel = function cancel (form) {
            $scope.is_hide = true;
            $scope.msg = null;
            if (form) {
                form.$setPristine();
            }
        };
    }]);
```

The `formName` argument is the name of the wrapper `form` element that you're using on your `HTML`, to access some specific properties, like `$setPristine`, which will reset the `form` processing to its initial state. NOTE: **This doesn't mean that the fields values will be reseted**.

Comment: thank you! and I find a way to solve, althrough it is not good.